# How do I get rid of black borders (video)?

Tags: video, scaling

first of all: I am aware that there must be black borders when the video format and the format of my screen do not match. However, my question refers to the situation that I get a black border on all 4 sides, as if my video has been scaled down (or, for nerds: as if I had a black padding around my video).

This problem occurs on my new monitor that has a resolution of 3440x1440 pixels (21:9).

For example, when I want to watch a movie in the VLC player, but also on Netflix, it's especially strange:
I started watching the third season of Star Trek Discovery today. The first episode fills my screen perfectly, the second episode has black borders all around, subtitles protrude slightly beyond the black border (so theyr relative position on the screen is are where they always are). I haven't changed anything between episodes, of course, and the phenomenon always occurs when I switch between episodes.

Are these several problems independent of each other? Does anyone know how I can fix them? Thanks in advance!

For visual clarification:

blue - entire screen, green - the boarders of the movie
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to crop the video using with VLC (right-click anywhere -> video -> crop). You should crop to 2.35:1 or 2.39:1 (which I usually find better) for 21:9 screen (21/9=2.33). Be careful to have the full image (compare it with the default setting).

You can also do the same with the aspect radio (right-click anywhere -> video -> aspect ratio) but you might want to keep the default aspect.

In both cases if you want to restore the original, chose the default option for crop and/or aspect ratio.